# Web scraping daily tables into CSV with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and am looking for some help with BeautifulSoup. I am trying to web scrape some baseball data from   http://contests.covers.com/Handicapping/consensusPick/daily-consensus-picks.aspx?sport=5&date=7/4/2014  and store the data into a CSV file. I would like to loop through each calendar date in the URL to grab the data from each day that a game is played.

I'm sure there are probably a few mistakes, but What I have so far looks something like this:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('covers.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(31):
        #I'd like to loop through actual dates instead of my 'i' here
        url = "http://contests.covers.com/Handicapping/consensusPick/daily-consensus-picks.aspx?sport=5&date=5/{}/2014".format(i)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            html = u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
        for mytable in soup.find_all(class="thepicks")
            for trs in mytable.find_all('tr')
                tds = trs.find_all('td')
                row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds]
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Use `datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(1)` to get tommorow date.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this.

Comment: Also, not all of my 'td's are being scraped. It only scrapes the data from where the tag is exactly <td>, but it's not grabbing the data if the <td... is followed by more arguments for the tag.

Comment: I suggest using [`urllib.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) and [`urlparse.urlunsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit) to build the URLs e.g. `urlparse.urlunsplit(('http', 'contests.covers.com', 'Handicapping/consensusPick/daily-consensus-picks.aspx',  urllib.urlencode({'sport': 5, 'date': '7/4/2014'}), ''))`.

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://contests.covers.com/Handicapping/consensusPick/daily-consensus-picks.aspx?sport=5&date=7/4/2014"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

for mytable in soup.find_all('table', 'thepicks'):
    for trs in mytable.find_all('tr'):
        tds = trs.find_all('td')
        row = [elem.text.strip().encode('utf-8') for elem in tds]
        print row
```

result

```
['Time', 'Away', 'Line', 'Picks', 'Pct', 'Home', 'Line', 'Picks', 'Pct', 'Detail', 'Odds']
['7:15 PM', 'Miami', '+133', '388', '29.02%', 'St. Louis', '-144', '949', '70.98%', 'View', 'View']
['7:08 PM', 'Tampa Bay', '+106', '444', '31.76%', 'Detroit', '-115', '954', '68.24%', 'View', 'View']
['7:35 PM', 'Arizona', '+145', '439', '33.13%', 'Atlanta', '-157', '886', '66.87%', 'View', 'View']
['5:05 PM', 'Philadelphia', '+180', '432', '34.70%', 'Pittsburgh', '-196', '813', '65.30%', 'View', 'View']
['9:05 PM', 'Houston', '+165', '507', '37.56%', 'LA Angels', '-179', '843', '62.44%', 'View', 'View']
['11:05 AM', 'Chi. Cubs', '+141', '388', '40.42%', 'Washington', '-153', '572', '59.58%', 'View', 'View']
['4:05 PM', 'Toronto', '+114', '541', '40.89%', 'Oakland', '-123', '782', '59.11%', 'View', 'View']
['7:10 PM', 'Seattle', '+161', '599', '45.14%', 'Chi. White Sox', '-175', '728', '54.86%', 'View', 'View']
['7:10 PM', 'Milwaukee', '+102', '614', '46.80%', 'Cincinnati', '-110', '698', '53.20%', 'View', 'View']
['3:10 PM', 'NY Yankees', '+100', '630', '50.28%', 'Minnesota', '-108', '623', '49.72%', 'View', 'View']
['7:05 PM', 'Kansas City', '+103', '706', '55.50%', 'Cleveland', '-111', '566', '44.50%', 'View', 'View']
['6:40 PM', 'San Francisco', '-108', '827', '60.63%', 'San Diego', '+100', '537', '39.37%', 'View', 'View']
['7:10 PM', 'Texas', '-153', '916', '67.60%', 'NY Mets', '+141', '439', '32.40%', 'View', 'View']
['8:10 PM', 'LA Dodgers', '-215', '946', '69.41%', 'Colorado', '+197', '417', '30.59%', 'View', 'View']
['Time', 'Away', 'Total', 'Home', 'Over', 'Pct', 'Under', 'Pct', 'Detail', 'Odds']
['7:10 PM', 'Seattle', '7.5', 'Chi. White Sox', '299', '38.93%', '469', '61.07%', 'View', 'View']
['8:10 PM', 'LA Dodgers', '9.5', 'Colorado', '230', '43.15%', '303', '56.85%', 'View', 'View']
['7:10 PM', 'Milwaukee', '7.5', 'Cincinnati', '373', '47.40%', '414', '52.60%', 'View', 'View']
['7:15 PM', 'Miami', '7.5', 'St. Louis', '360', '48.19%', '387', '51.81%', 'View', 'View']
['11:05 AM', 'Chi. Cubs', '7', 'Washington', '257', '48.22%', '276', '51.78%', 'View', 'View']
['7:35 PM', 'Arizona', '7.0', 'Atlanta', '379', '50.40%', '373', '49.60%', 'View', 'View']
['4:05 PM', 'Toronto', '8', 'Oakland', '392', '52.34%', '357', '47.66%', 'View', 'View']
['7:08 PM', 'Tampa Bay', '8', 'Detroit', '421', '54.89%', '346', '45.11%', 'View', 'View']
['3:10 PM', 'NY Yankees', '8', 'Minnesota', '402', '55.76%', '319', '44.24%', 'View', 'View']
['5:05 PM', 'Philadelphia', '7.5', 'Pittsburgh', '426', '57.26%', '318', '42.74%', 'View', 'View']
['7:10 PM', 'Texas', '6.5', 'NY Mets', '278', '57.68%', '204', '42.32%', 'View', 'View']
['6:40 PM', 'San Francisco', '7', 'San Diego', '482', '58.14%', '347', '41.86%', 'View', 'View']
['9:05 PM', 'Houston', '8', 'LA Angels', '478', '58.51%', '339', '41.49%', 'View', 'View']
['7:05 PM', 'Kansas City', '7.5', 'Cleveland', '461', '60.58%', '300', '39.42%', 'View', 'View']
```

If you need to add column:

```
row = [elem.text.strip().encode('utf-8') for elem in tds]
row.append("7/4/2014")
```

If you need to modify existing columns:
(for example remove columns with text `View`)

```
row = []

for elem in tds:
    text = elem.text.strip().encode('utf-8')
    if text != 'View':
        row.append( text )

row.append("7/4/2014")
```

Comment: Now if I can just figure out how to add text into an adjacent column to the data scraped from this for each row which contains the date that the games were held on... hmm :)

Comment: `row.append("7/4/2014")` ?

Comment: Seriously excellent answer.  @user3808992 please mark it correct.